# How does three.js run shader programs

Tags: three.js

I want to understand how `three.js` works internally. One thing I don't understand is how `three.js` compiles and runs shader programs. If I were to reimplement `three.js` myself I would have a vertex shader attributed to a `Geometry` and a fragment shader attributed to a `Material` and then generate a shader program when they are combined in `Mesh`. But looking at the geometries and the materials they don't seem to reference any shader. Furthermore, the shaders (in the folder `three.js/src/renderers/shaders/`) in the project don't seem to be attributed to any specific `Geometry`/`Material`. I was wondering whether someone could shed light on how the `three.js` compiles and runs shaders.

Comment: https://medium.com/@pailhead011/extending-three-js-materials-with-glsl-78ea7bbb9270 This article touches on the topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that `Geometry` is internally converted `BufferGeometry`. Instances of `BufferGeometry` do have attribute data which are later mapped to the respective shader program.

The default shader attributes which are available in all materials expect `RawShaderMaterial` are listed in the documentation of [WebGLProgram](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram). Additional custom attributes are not automatically added to shader source code. You have to enhance built-in materials or write a custom shader program in order to add such attributes to your GLSL code.